# Normalized screen size in Android

Tags: android, fonts, size, metrics

In one of my Activities I'd like to adjust an amount of textual content according to current screen size. What metric should I rely on?

Just width in pixels seems not too reliable since font scaling can be very different. On the other hand `DisplayMetrics`'s `DENSITY_280, DENSITY_400 ...` seem too broad. Is there any normalized metric available like `width_in_pixels * font_scaling`?

Just in case: My min SDK verion is 15 (4.0.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get values like dpi from `DisblayMetrics` , look here [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#xdpi)

also, there is a built-in converter for different size metrics in api, [TypedValue.applyDimension()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#applyDimension(int,%20float,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics)) , which can be used to get pixels from sp or dp

Answer (score 1):

When specifying text size, always use sp:

```
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)